# Approach on Reversing a Linked List in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I tried the following code to reverse a linked list and is getting an infinite loop as an error. Can you pls tell me what's wrong in this approach.

```
def reverse(self):
   temp  = curr = self.head         #curr refers to the next node
   prev = None
   while temp:
          curr = temp.next    #curr goes to the next node of temp           
          curr.next = temp    #curr node points to its previous node temp
          prev = temp         #prev moves to the next node
          temp = curr
   #self.head.next = None 
   self.head = prev
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a logic error in your method.

At the end of the first pass of the while loop:

- curr *(2nd element in list)*
- curr.next *(1st element in list)*
- temp = curr *= (2nd element in list)*

In the second pass of the while loop. You expect to reach the 3rd element using temp.next. This is wrong because:

- temp.next = curr.next = *(1st element in list)*

Leaving you to loop infinitely between the first and second element with no exit condition.

I will leave you to figure out the proper solution for this.

(Hint: temp should be assigned to the ??? element in the 1st pass)

Comment: The secret is the [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant), that you point out.

Comment: Thanks! it helped.